# Getting data from a webservice c# javascript ajax

Tags: c#, ajax

I really need help with getting data from my webservice, but all I get is "internal server error". The desired result is to be able to have a webservice return data to my javascript function.

Yesterday I was successfully able to call a webservice, but not able to get data from it.

Below is my javascript code which I understand is executed on the client

---

```
    function Test(myid) {
        var projects;
        var opt = document.getElementById(myid);
        var constring = '<%=this.ConnectionText %>';
        document.getElementById("Text1").value = opt.value;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Overview.aspx/ExecuteSelectListBox',            
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function (data) {
                projects = data.d;
            },
            error: function (requeset, status, error) {
                alert( error);
            }
        });
}
```

---

If succesful then projects should become "hello world"

Below is my C# code which I have understood is executed on the server.
However, I dont think my function on the server is called at all. If I replace Overview.aspx with something else I get "not found" from server instead of "internal server error".
But the "executelistbox" itself I can call whatever and I still get "internal server error" and not "not found".

---

```
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class AjaxWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        /**************************************************
        *** Returns a datatable with projectnames. ***
        *************************************************/
        public static string ExecuteSelectListBox()
        {
            return "hello world";
        }
    }
```

---

So the desired problem is to be able to retrieve data from a webservice written in c#. Both c# and javascript are actually part of the same webpage in this example. I keep it minimalistic. I hope others can use this too, as a basic example how youre able to get data from your webserver. In the future I will make database calls from the server and send back to the client, but I cannot even think about this now, as I even cant get "hello world" to work :)

I would be so grateful if anyone could help!! I tried posted this before but was shut "on hold".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at the following tutorial and use WebApi instead of System.Web.WebService. You are making it yourself rather difficult.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api

At the moment you're requesting Json, but im not sure whether you are actually returning Json, but perhaps xml?

Comment: Hmm your example works... but not when I try to do the same to my webpage....  perhaps the difference is that my webpage is a webpage and your example is an application. Ive tried to make an exact copy of global.asax, but then it says that global.asax doesnt contain valid data when I "play" my webpage. And its exactly the same as in your application example....

Comment: I coudnt get it to work in my projekt, so I took your example, and added my entire code of 5 webpages and some c# classes to it :) Now it works. The backside is that I dont really know why it didnt work, and whats different from my project and your example.

Comment: The example in the webapi can be used in an application and a web project. For example in an MVC project you can use this. Im glad you got it working. The WebApi class is more modern and you need to do less work to get things going.